# Как можно проигрывать короткие звуки в android

Tags: android, аудио

Необходим метод проигрывания коротких сэмплов при, например, нажатии на кнопку. Как с самыми меньшими затратами мощностей устройства это сделать? И ещё вопрос вдогонку- есть на примете какие-нибудь бесплатные звукобанки, откуда можно брать необходимые ресурсы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этих целей используйте [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)